# Xcode 8 Archive Error with Apple

Tags: app-store-connect, archive, xcode8

I have a project I updated using `Xcode 8` and `Swift 3`. It runs fine and I'm ready to submit to Apple.  I complete the Archive process and then click 'Validate' in Organizer.  After a while it gave me the following error, twice:

[image]

I tried to search online for this error and can't find anything.  Why am I getting this error?  I've agreed to all the Terms and Conditions set by Apple in the iTunes Connect side of things.  All of my certificates and Profiles are Active too.  Is Apple just having issues right now?  I've seen others get around this issue with using the Application Uploader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a fix but I did as others suggested in the past and uploaded the `.ipa` file to Apple using the Application Loader that is in Xcode already.  Worked and received confirmation it reached Apple.